# <Link> onClick is causing my page to refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a navigation bar on my site that fires off a function passed in from props when they are clicked, like so:

```
<Filter 
  filter={this.props.params.filter}
  sub={this.props.params.sub}
  search={this.props.location.search}
  fetchData={() => this.fetchData}  />
```

Filter Component:

```
<Link to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/new/${this.props.search}`} onClick={this.props.fetchData()}>
 <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">New</span>
</Link>
<Link to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/rising/${this.props.search}`} onClick={this.props.fetchData()}>
 <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Rising</span>
</Link>
```

Fetch Data:

```
      fetchData() {
        if (this.props.params.sub) {
          if (this.props.params.filter) {
              let query = `${this.props.params.sub}/${this.props.params.filter}`;

              this.props.fetchList(query, this.props.location.search);
          }
      }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever one of these link tags is clicked it refreshes the entire page. While this works I'd prefer the page didn't refresh. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe remove the arrow function the `fetchData` prop. Instead, use `fetchData={this.fetchData}` and check whether that works.

Comment: I tried that, but wind up getting `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` from fetchData (I updated the post with it). I'm using the react-router data on the parent component as arguments to the function. I've tried doing `{this.fetchData.bind(this}` but seem to wind up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you binding `fetchData` in your component's constructor? That should be the cause of this error now.

Comment: Ah yeah, that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the answer and, maybe, that can help others: you forgot to bind the event handler in the component's constructor.

```
export default YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this)
  }

  fetchData() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Link
        to={`/r/${this.props.sub}/new/${this.props.search}`}
        onClick={this.fetchData}
      >
        <span className="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">New</span>
      </Link>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: I just had this happen to me, and I've got to say this is some extremely weird unexpected behavior. How in the world would not binding a function cause a page refresh before an error!? Anyways, thanks for the help.