# URL with ID not handled by React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using `React Router` v4 in my `ReactJs` app and looks like whenever I have a path with an ID in it, `React Router` is not handling it because I see the page refreshing and I'm losing all the data in my `Redux` store in the process.

Here's my routes section:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/member" component={Home} />
   <Route exact path="/member/accounts" component={Accounts} />
   <Route path="/member/projects/profile/:id" component={ProjectProfile} />
</Switch>
```

Here's how I'm generating the link. This is the link when the user clicks, I see a refresh on my browser.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

... omitted for brevity
const profileUrl = "/member/projects/profile/" + project.id;

<Link to={profileUrl}>Click here</Link>
```

Other links defined in my routes work fine e.g. home and accounts.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Problem is not with your router config. The page should not refresh. That's not the router behaviour. Are you submitting any form when you're trying to change the route?

Comment: No, this particular component just renders a list of projects and all I'm doing is generating their URLs with this code. This is in a very simple presentational component.

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: No errors. The console refreshes too because technically I'm getting a new page. I'm trying to catch any possible errors before the refresh and I don't see any. After the refresh, there are no errors.

Comment: What do your ids look like? Are they just numbers?

Comment: ^ Yep. Can you please share what `profileUrl` returns?

Comment: They're GUID's (UUID). So here's a typical URL for a project:
`/member/projects/profile/ba88958d-db81-4e4a-8bea-16a61253a98a`

Comment: @JordanEnev Just posted it in a comment that I posted in response to another question. I double checked it to make sure it's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Others report a similar issue on the same version of `react-router-dom` that I'm using which is `4.2.2` but I don't see any responses: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/4066

Comment: can you post the `ProjectProfile` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I found the cause. We must use `NavLink` or `Link` from `react-router-dom` whenever linking to a component.

I noticed I wasn't consistent in using `NavLink` in my app. Instead I was using regular

`<a href={myModuleUrl}>Module Name</a>`.

Once I switched to using `NavLink`, it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass `onClick` event handler to the `Link` component?

If so make sure everything is fine with the handler. You can try to remove it temporarily, in order to debug the refreshing.

Credits:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115304/4312466
2. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/4066#issuecomment-383910759

Comment: No event handlers at all. The code I posted is almost all there's to it in the actual component. It's a very simple component. Interestingly, I have a similar approach elsewhere and I'm getting the same behavior. So whenever, I have an ID in the path, the page refreshes.